# Ansible hostvars not defined when fetching a secret and setting it as a fact from azure

Tags: azure, ansible

**I was trying to fetch a secret from azure keyvault which worked but trying to pass that secret into another playbook doesn't work**

**Yaml code for playbook:**

```
- name: "FetchSecretExample"
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: yes
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Get latest version of Username
      azure.azcollection.azure_rm_keyvaultsecret_info:
        auth_source: msi
        vault_uri: "https://{somevault}.vault.azure.net/"
        name: User
      register: UserName
    - name: Get latest version of Password
      azure.azcollection.azure_rm_keyvaultsecret_info:
        auth_source: msi
        vault_uri: "https://{somevault}.vault.azure.net/"
        name: Pass
      register: Password
    - name: Make vars persistant
      set_fact:
        _user: UserName.secrets[0].secret
        _pass: Password.secrets[0].secret
    - name: Print Password
      debug:
        var: "{{_pass}}"

- name: "localInstall"
  hosts: data
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Print Password
      debug:
        var: "{{hostvars['localhost']['_pass']}}"
```

**Console output:**

```
[WARNING]: Ansible is being run in a world writable directory (/etc/ansible), ignoring it as an ansible.cfg source. For more information see
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/reference_appendices/config.html#cfg-in-world-writable-dir
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Ansible will require Python 3.8 or newer on the controller starting with Ansible 2.12. Current version: 3.6.9 (default, Jan 26 2021,
 15:33:00) [GCC 8.4.0]. This feature will be removed from ansible-core in version 2.12. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting
deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
[WARNING]: No setting was provided for required configuration plugin_type: cache plugin: ansible_collections.community.general.plugins.cache.redis setting:
_uri

PLAY [gather facts] ****************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.0.2.4]

PLAY [FetchSecretExample] **********************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Get latest version of Username] **********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Get latest version of Password] **********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Make vars persistant] ********************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Print Password] **************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "Password.secrets[0].secret": "RandomPasswordGOGOGO"
}

PLAY [localInstall] ****************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.0.2.4]

TASK [Print Password] **************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.0.2.4] => {
    "Password.secrets[0].secret": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************
10.0.2.4                   : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
localhost                  : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I have tried multiple things, over the last like a day or so but I can't really figure out what's wrong with the approach.
hostvars was undefined even when trying to output it alone.
My goal is to just pass the secret that I have fetched as the become_ansible_password in the  next play to configure a windows vm through Winrm. For that fetching this secret is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a small cascade of problems here.

First, in your `set_fact` task...

```
    - name: Make vars persistant
      set_fact:
        _user: UserName.secrets[0].secret
        _pass: Password.secrets[0].secret
```

...you're setting the value of `_user` to the *literal value* `UserName.secrets[0].secret`, rather than the contents of that variable (and similarly for `_pass`). You want to use instead:

```
    - name: Make vars persistant
      set_fact:
        _user: "{{ UserName.secrets[0].secret }}"
        _pass: "{{ Password.secrets[0].secret }}"
```

Secondly, you are misusing the `debug` module.  When you use the `var` key, it expects the *name* of variable, but you're using Jinja template so you're passing the *value* of the variable to `var`. It works in the first case because when you write:

```
    - name: Print Password
      debug:
        var: "{{_pass}}"
```

This is exactly the same as if you had written:

```
    - name: Print Password
      debug:
        var: Password.secrets[0].secret
```

...because of the error in the `set_fact` task.  Since `Password.secrets[0].secret` exists in the first play, this succeeds and you see the value you expect.

But!

In the second task, when you try the same thing...

```
    - name: Print Password
      debug:
        msg: "{{hostvars['localhost']['_pass']}}"
```

...there is no `Password.secrets[0].secret`, so you get the error in your question.

Everything will work as expected if you fix these two problems. That will give you a playbook that looks something like:

```
- name: "FetchSecretExample"
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: true
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Get latest version of Username
      azure.azcollection.azure_rm_keyvaultsecret_info:
        auth_source: msi
        vault_uri: "https://{somevault}.vault.azure.net/"
        name: User
      register: UserName

    - name: Get latest version of Password
      azure.azcollection.azure_rm_keyvaultsecret_info:
        auth_source: msi
        vault_uri: "https://{somevault}.vault.azure.net/"
        name: Pass
      register: Password

    - name: Make vars persistant
      set_fact:
        _user: "{{ UserName.secrets[0].secret }}"
        _pass: "{{ Password.secrets[0].secret }}"

    - name: Print Password
      debug:
        var: _pass

- name: "localInstall"
  hosts: data
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
    - name: Print Password
      debug:
        var: hostvars.localhost._pass
```

(Note that in the final task `hostvars.localhost._pass` is exactly the
same as writing `hostvars['localhost']['_pass']`, but requires much
less typing.)

---

For reference purposes, here is the playbook I used for testing all
this out locally, where I don't have access to azure:

```
- name: "FetchSecretExample"
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    Username:
      secrets:
        - secret: foo
    Password:
      secrets:
        - secret: bar
  tasks:
    - name: Make vars persistant
      set_fact:
        _user: "{{ Username.secrets[0].secret }}"
        _pass: "{{ Password.secrets[0].secret }}"

    - name: Print Password
      debug:
        var: _pass

- name: "localInstall"
  hosts: remotehost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Print Password
      debug:
        var: hostvars.localhost._pass
```

And the associated inventory file:

```
all:
  hosts:
    remotehost:
      ansible_host: 127.0.0.1
      connection: ssh
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying. This worked perfectly and I understood the way hostvars works and how we can pass values properly.